# pointers replacing themselves in struct arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Ok so I have this code where it pulls various things from a file

```
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) !=NULL)
{
    name = strtok(buffer,del);
    class=strtok(NULL,del);
    grade = atoi(strtok(NULL,del));


    d[counter].name=name;
    d[counter].course=class;
    d[counter].grade=grade;
    printf("%s    %s     %d\n",d[counter].name,d[counter].course,d[counter].grade);
    counter++;
}
```

now the problem is that everytime a new token from strtok is retrieved it replaced the previous values in the struct array.

I have narrowed it down to this block being problematic:

```
d[counter].name=name;
d[counter].course=class;
```

It seems like it is pointing to the same memory block which gets re-written everytime the strtok returns a new value and thus all my pointers in the struct point to that 1 object.

here is my struct:

```
struct student {
char *name;
char *course;
int grade;

};
```

Now my question is, that is there anyway to put the strtok values into seperate memory addresses so they don't point all to just 1 location and replace themselves?

Strdup, malloc and memmove are not options for me.

for a clearer representation of what is happening, here is the crude expected output

```
Tom    Phys 1444   54
Joe    CSE 1310   95
Alex   Chem 2315   86
Tim    Span 1443   81
```

Now this is the output I am getting

```
Tim  Span 1443  54
Tim  Span 1443  95
Tim  Span 1443  86
Tim  Span 1443  81
```

Comment: Look up `malloc` and `strcpy`.

Comment: i edited the post, not supposed to use malloc as well.

Comment: **Why** is `malloc` not an option? Explicitly forbidden?

Comment: @Daniel yes, it's not allowed for this specific assignment (although I am using for the next one)

Comment: @Armin then is there a more elegant way to do it than the way I am doing it right now?

Comment: Have you any guarantees about the lengths of the names and courses?

Comment: yes:
1. a student name with at most 9 characters
2. a course name with 7–9 characters
3. an integer in the range of 0-100 representing the grade tha
t this student received in this
course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a single buffer that is overwritten every time you call `fgets` and the calls to `strtok` are just returning pointers into that buffer.

If you aren't allowed to use something like `strdup` to copy the strings returned from the `strtok` calls then I would suggest you just use multiple buffers.

For example if your buffer is currently declared as:

```
char buffer[256];
```

you could instead declare 20 buffers as:

```
char buffer[20][256];
```

where 20 should be at least as large as the number of items in your *d* array.

Then your call to `fgets` should read into a different buffer on each iteration of the loop based on the counter.

```
fgets(buffer[counter], sizeof(buffer[counter]), fp)
```

Similarly your call to `strtok` should reference the appropriate buffer.

```
name = strtok(buffer[counter],del);
```